Падает тест после обновления версии Django
Столкнулся с проблемой после обновления с django 3.1 на 4.2.
Есть тест на создание устройства два раза подряд с идентичными данными:
@parameterized.expand([(MOBILE_APP_KIND.INSPECTOR,), (MOBILE_APP_KIND.VOLUNTEER,)])
def test_double_create_device(self, app_kind):
    if app_kind == MOBILE_APP_KIND.INSPECTOR:
        url = self.url_inspector
        InspectorFactory(user=self.user)
    else:
        url = self.url_volunteer
    response = self.client.post(url, self.data, format="json")
    print(response.data)

    self.assertEqual(response.status_code, 201)
    devices = self.user.fcm_devices
    self.assertEqual(devices.count(), 1)

    response = self.client.post(url, self.data, format="json")
    print(response.data)

    self.assertEqual(response.status_code, 201)
    self.user.refresh_from_db()
    devices = self.user.fcm_devices
    self.assertEqual(devices.count(), 1)

При добавлении второго устройства представление должно просто вернуть последнее устройство из БД, вместо создания, дабы избежать ошибок с уникальностью registration_id.
class FCMViewSet(FCMDeviceAuthorizedViewSet):
    serializer_class = CommonFCMDeviceSerializer
    http_method_names = ["post", "delete"]

    def get_object(self):
        return get_object_or_404(
            FCMDevice,
            registration_id=self.kwargs.get("registration_id"),
            user=self.request.user,
            active=True,
        )

    def destroy(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        instance = self.get_object()
        instance.active = False
        instance.save()
        return Response(status=status.HTTP_204_NO_CONTENT)

class CommonFCMDeviceSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    user = serializers.HiddenField(default=serializers.CurrentUserDefault())
    app = serializers.ChoiceField(
        choices=MOBILE_APP_KIND, required=True, write_only=True
    )

    class Meta(FCMSerializer.Meta):
        model = FCMDevice
        fields = (
            "user",
            "app",
            "name",
            "registration_id",
            "device_id",
            "active",
            "type",
        )

    def create(self, validated_data):
        devices = FCMDevice.objects.filter(
            user=validated_data["user"],
            app=validated_data["app"],
            registration_id=validated_data["registration_id"],
            active=True,
            type=validated_data["type"],
        )
        if devices.exists():
            return devices.last()
        return FCMDevice.objects.create(**validated_data)

Пробовал использовать create_or_update, пробовал часть логики переносить на уровень представления - ничего не помогло.
======================================================================
FAIL: test_double_create_device_0_inspector (api.mobile.common.v2.test.test_fcm_device.FCMCreateTestCase.test_double_create_device_0_inspector)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\xacla\AppData\Local\pypoetry\Cache\virtualenvs\core-2EZgQNjY-py3.11\Lib\site-packages\parameterized\parameterized.py", line 533, in standalone_func
    return func(*(a + p.args), **p.kwargs)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\xacla\Desktop\Work\Work\DobroFon.Core\core\www\api\mobile\common\v2\test\test_fcm_device.py", line 89, in test_double_create_device
    self.assertEqual(response.status_code, 201)
AssertionError: 400 != 201

{'name': '', 'registration_id': 'test_reg_id', 'device_id': 'test_dev_id', 'active': True, 'type': 'ios'}
{'registration_id': [ErrorDetail(string='FCM device with this Registration token already exists.', code='unique')]}
{'name': '', 'registration_id': 'test_reg_id', 'device_id': 'test_dev_id', 'active': True, 'type': 'ios'}
{'registration_id': [ErrorDetail(string='FCM device with this Registration token already exists.', code='unique')]}

